# Good book about finite element methods in a multiphysics context for self study

Tags: self-learning, book-recommendation, finite-element-method

I am looking for guidance on what to read. I have to learn FEM pretty much on my own and will have to work on multiphysics problems, including the interaction between solid mechanics, fluid mechanics, diffusion (heat and matter), (electro)chemical reactions. So there is a lot of people on the plate and I don't know where to start exactly. Any suggestion would be really welcome !

My problem is to understand FEM and be able to apply it, possibly using freefem or any similar open source code.

Thanks a lot !

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while I started studying FEM, one of the best books I found was:

Numerical Solutions of PDE by Finite Element Method- Claes Johnson, Cambridge University Press.

It's a basic book and develops the theory pretty easily. You do not need to know Functional Analysis to understand this work.

For advanced FEM, I suggest

Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Methods- Brenner and Scott

This is a little involved and would expect the reader to know a little about Functional Analysis.

For implementation using C++, I suggest

Finite Elements: Theory and Algorithm- Sashikumar Ganesan and Lutz Tobiska, IISc-Cambrdige press

This has some basics on how to apply FEM to the C++ environment.

There is a new book, I came to know about which has MATLAB implementation but I personally have not studied this book:

MATLAB Codes for Finite Element Analysis- Antonio Ferreria, Nicholas Fantuzzi, Springer.

For multiphysics problems, I would suggest finding books that are relevant to your field

Comment: Thank you so much for these references ! I had Claes : it is now on top of my list. I didn't know the other books : I am going to hunt them down on amazon ;-)